# How to add ActionBar to an activity which already extends ListActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I have an Activity which extends `ListActivity`.
Can I add an `ActionBar` without extending `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: post your styles.xml

Comment: Please see here, I think this is solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532346/adding-actionbar-to-listactivity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the new [AppCompatDelegate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) component provided by the Support Library.

ActionBar is now deprecated and you should use a `Toolbar`, to be compliant with Material Design. You can use the Toolbar provided by the support library.

Add it to your xml layout like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        />
```

Be sure to use a `NoActionBar` theme in your styles.xml. Use the Material Design color tags.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Then, add the `AppCompatDelegate` to your Activity, in OnCreate(), like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AppCompatCallback callback = new AppCompatCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }
    };

    AppCompatDelegate delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this,callback);

    delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}
```

**Note:** To create an AppCompatDelegate you need to pass the Activity itself and a callback, good practice should be implementing the callback in your Activity, but for shortening reasons I created an instance in onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

Use holo themes in styles.xml Because you can use ActionBar only after holo

Use this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Toolbar** : add a AppCompat Toolbar to your Activity Layout.

**Tutorial** (go to ActionBar): http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

**Documentation** : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html